# Using `ugettext` in a definition of a Django field

Tags: django, internationalization, gettext

In my `models.py` file I define a field on a model like this:

```
description = models.CharField(
    max_length=40,
    default=_('Bla bla bla'),
)
```

Now, `_` is `django.utils.translation.ugettext`, and I want to use as a default value the Hebrew translation of `'Bla bla bla'`, which is `'בלה בלה בלה'`. (The website is in Hebrew only.) The string is properly translated in the messages file. But when I run the Django admin and create a new object, I see the English `'bla bla bla'` on the field. I assume that English is the active language when compiling the `models.py` module. How can I solve this and make it Hebrew?

I know that one solution would be to forego `ugettext` and just write Hebrew inside the Python module, but I prefer to avoid that in order to prevent encoding hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ugettext_lazy`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/#lazy-translation

> Always use lazy translations in Django
>   models.

Answer (score 1):

ugettext merely marks strings as translatable. It doesn't do any translation for you, per se. You have to create language files (.mo and .po) and then set the LANGUAGE_CODE setting to match. Read the [Django documentation on Internationalization and Localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) for more in depth info.